# Daedalus fails to load wallet

Tags: wallet, daedalus

Daedalus after 4.2.1 upgrade fails to load my wallet, the logs says the wallet was found, I can see some sqlite wallet files on my computer and cannot seem to find any information about anything being errorous, the only error I can spot in the logs are saying:

```
[34m[cardano-wallet.pools-engine:Info:1340][0m [2021-08-20 17:13:04.65 UTC] Fetching metadata with hash 7e10ed9d from https://smash.cardano-mainnet.iohk.io/api/v1/metadata/<bighexnumber>/<bighexnumber>
[33m[cardano-wallet.pools-engine:Warning:1340][0m [2021-08-20 17:13:04.81 UTC] Failed to fetch metadata with hash 7e10ed9d: There's no known metadata for this pool.
```

Can I somehow fix my wallet information without the seed phrase?

Comment: Please submit a support ticket within Daedalus.